# Advanced custom field boolean value in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the Advanced Custom Field (ACF) plugin in a Custom Post Type (CPT).

I have field group in ACF that contains a Image field and true/false field called 'home_offer'.

I'm using this ACF in a Custom Post Type called Offers.

I want to loop through the CPT Offers and check if the true/false field 'home_offer' is checked.

How do I check if the true/false field is selected.

Ive started with this WP_Query.

```
    <div id="offers">
            <?php
                $offers_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'Offers',
                    'post_per_page' => 1,
                    'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key'       => 'home_offer',
                                'value'     => 'on',
                                'compare' => '=', 
                                'type'      => 'CHAR'
                            );
                    );
                );

                $offers_loop = new WP_Query($offers_args);

                if($offers_loop->have_posts()):
                    while($offers_loop->have_posts()):
                        $offers_loop->the_post();

                $image = get_field('image');        

            ?>

            <div id="offerLeft">

                <img src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt="" />

            </div>  

            <?php

                endwhile;
                endif;

                wp_reset_postdata();

            ?>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `'post_per_page' => 1` in your code is wrong, right name of the argument is **posts_per_page** (note the plural in postS_per_page)

then if you want query for a 'true/false' field in ACF you have to use

```
'meta_query' => array(
  array(
    'key' => 'home_offer',
    'value' => '1',
    'compare' => '=='
  )
)
```

See [ACF docs](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/true-false/)

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for WordPress >= 3.5 ([source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/126088/65669)). I couldn't get it to work the [ACF way](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/110948). No need to use 'meta_query' this way. Just replace 'meta_query' with the following two lines to offer_args and and it should work.

```
'meta_key'     =>   'home_offer',
'meta_compare' =>   'EXISTS', // or 'NOT EXISTS' if no offer.
```